# MultiTenantConnectionProvider implementation has null autowired datasource

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

I'm trying to support a multi-tenant by schema in my spring boot (1.4) application. I have the following in my config:

```
hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        default_schema: corrto
        multiTenancy: SCHEMA
        tenant_identifier_resolver: com.config.HeaderTenantIdentifierResolver
        multi_tenant_connection_provider: com.config.SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider
```

My MultiTenantConnectionProvider implementation is as follows:

```
public class SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider implements MultiTenantConnectionProvider {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Override
    public Connection getAnyConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.dataSource.getConnection();
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseAnyConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
        connection.close();
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection(String tenantIdentifier) throws SQLException {
        final Connection connection = this.getAnyConnection();
        // need to do stuff here
        return connection;
    }

    @Override
    public void releaseConnection(String tenantIdentifier, Connection connection) throws SQLException {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isUnwrappableAs(Class unwrapType) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T unwrap(Class<T> unwrapType) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

It is failing because `dataSource` is null. I'm assuming it hasn't been created yet but I'm having a hard time finding solutions via Google.

Comment: Have you setup the datasource?

Comment: Should not `SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider` be annotated with `@Component` in order to be autowired?

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem.It seems that in the `yml` ,`HeaderTenantIdentifierResolver` and `SchemaPerTenantConnectionProvider` is managed by hibernate.See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26898896/spring-boot-spring-data-with-multi-tenancy/26903310).