# Multitenancy in Hibernate using both Schema and Database

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, multi-tenant

The application has 2 separate databases, say:

- **DB1**
- **DB2**

and database of different companies are split across these 2 databases, like:

- DB1

  - Company 1
  - Company 2
  - Company 3
  - Company 4
- DB2

  - Company 5
  - Company 6
  - Company 7
  - Company 8

How can such a scenario be configured in hibernate?
All the examples refer either to Schema based multitenancy or Database multitenancy.

Is there any way to configure such a scenario?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to just go for database multitenancy? The schema based multitenancy works well for smaller datasets, but combining the two isn't really worth doing. Instead you would have `Server1` and `Server2` (provided you have multiple database servers) with each having 4 databases for companies.

Comment: @Kayaman Database structure is already defined, this is an existing application. I cannot change that.

Comment: Configure two `DataSource`s, one for DB1 and another for DB2. Create two implementations of [`AbstractRoutingDataSource`](https://spring.io/blog/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/) - one that allows selecting the data source for DB1 for the current client; and another that allows selecting the data source for DB2. Lastly, create a third implementation of `AbstractRoutingDataSource` that allows selecting one of the other two `AbstractRoutingDataSource` implementations for the current client. The linked blog has all the information required.

Answer (score 0):

To do that you should create two sessionFactory Bean in your config file. and in your DAO layer you call it using qualifier annotation.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to create your own implementation of `MultiTenantConnectionProvider` that handles both database and schema level multitenancy. That should be the path of least resistance.

Here's some slightly outdated info about fighting with spring, hibernate and custom multitenancy: [Setting up a MultiTenantConnectionProvider using Hibernate 4.2 and Spring 3.1.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16213573/setting-up-a-multitenantconnectionprovider-using-hibernate-4-2-and-spring-3-1-1)

Answer (score 0):

I will get strategy with separate database and in ConnectionProvider override method `getConnection()` to set schema.
I this case I can change databases and select specyfic schema for tenant.